# How does one populate a collection if the types of elements in it are of interface type? (Java)

Tags: java, collections, interface

It was a question from a job interview test that I had earlier.  I have no idea why someone would want to do this or if it is even possible, but how would someone populate this collection?

```
Collection<MyLinks> links = null;    //Populate this variable

public interface MyLinks() {
    //Method headers only
}
```

How can I fill this collection if MyLinks objects cannot be instantiated?  Was this a trick question?

Comment: fill it with `null` :)

Comment: @JigarJoshi:  Heh.  Technically correct, yet totally useless; a good answer to toss-off before moving on to the real one.  :-)

Comment: This doesn't compile.  Why are there parentheses after `public interface MyLinks` ?

Comment: "_I have no idea why someone would want to do this_" - probably because it's a **best practice** to program to the interface.

Answer (score 2):

Fill the collection with objects which *implement* the interface.

```
public interface MyInterface {
  int getANumber();
}

public class RandomNumberGenerator implements MyInterface {
  public int getANumber() {
    return 4; // choosen by a fair dice roll
  }
}

Collection<MyInterface> collection = new ArrayList<MyInterface>();
collection.add(new RandomNumberGenerator());
```

Hint: Do not copy the code if you need a random number generator.

Answer (score 1):

Such a collection can be filled with any objects whose class implements that interface.  The objects can be of different classes (even anonymous classes), as long as those classes implement that interface.

```
class ConcreteMyLinks implements MyLinks...
class ConcreteMyLinks2 implements MyLinks...

ConcreteMyLinks obj = new ConcreteMyLinks();
ConcreteMyLinks2 obj2 = new ConcreteMyLinks2();
collection.add(obj);
collection.add(obj2);
collection.add(new MyLinks() {  /* implement interface here */ });
```

Answer (score 1):

You create a class that implements the interface, and fill it with that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this mate:

```
    links = new ArrayList<MyLinks>();
    links.add(new MyLinks() { });
```

Good luck!

Comment: Correct... since in the code snippet above, it doesn't :) If it does - just implement stubs after new MyLinks() between the curly brackets.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions above are correct, you can also use anonymous classes:

```
MyInterface object = new MyInterface() {
   //here override interfaces' methods
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create instances of a concrete class that implements that interface and add it to the
   collection.

   ```
   collection.add(new MyConcreteLinks());
   ```
2. you can create anonymous class instances like:

   ```
   collection.add(new MyLinks() { /*overide mylinks method*/});
   ```